Possibility to limit default listening address to specific ip
I had a use case where I wanted to limit default listening directives like "*:443" to a specific port.
The conflict was triggered when listening on a loopback ip like "127.0.54.1:443" while having a default listening configuration "*:443"
Is there a directive within linux to redirect default listening configurations to a single ip or interface?

No.
*:443 is something from an Apache2 httpd or nginx configuration; it literally means "bind the port using INADDR_ANY"; so you're explicitly demand that this is bound to all network interfaces in this network namespace.
Your only option is to change the visible interfaces, using Linux network namespaces; but that affects whole processes (i.e., the whole apache2), and can't be used to isolate things done by configuring the same daemon.
In other words:
You have a self-contradicting configuration; and you need to fix that. Linux can't help you with that

I was hoping for a way to configure this system wide to avoid having to configure in a variable amount of places.
For my hobby project I utilize a lot of different ips on a single system and thus don't really want to change every default configuration.
Sometimes it is just as it is

I'm afraid that's simply not how the network stack works. You could instead of an IP address use a host name, which you could set e.g. via /etc/hosts to whatever currently makes sense. But really, especially if you have multiple changing interfaces, you'll simply have to make sure your daemon configuration matches your reality, or you need to isolate the things (e.g. have a separate apache container for each interface you might serve, and start these containers as the interfaces come up and stop them as they go down).

I think you want to look at one of two Apache config setups. The first is the Listen directive, which is set by default to 80 and 443. You can put in a hostname to use Listen www.example.com:443 or Listen 172.24.27.2:443 to limit to a specific host. You can have multiple Listen directives in your config. Just remember to take out any directives that don't include a hostname or address.
The other option is in your vhost line. Using <VirtualHost www.example.com:443> will direct traffic to a URI using that host to that specific config. You can then have a second default vhost defined using *:443 that ignores all other traffic.
